# Splitting data into test and train and not including all the column

Tags: r, testing, training-data

I am working with the Auto data set in the ISLR library. How do I split the data into 75% train and 25% test. I think I split it right but I cant figure out howo to not include the two columns

Create a train and a test set

a.  75% train, 25% test

b.  set seed to 1234 to get reproducible results

c.  do not include columns “name” and “mpg” in the train and test sets

```
   splitTheData <- sample(nrow(Default), nrow(Default)*0.75, replace=FALSE)
   #3b
   set.seed(1234)

   #3c
```

Comment: I am not supposed to include those column

Comment: a. `set.seed` before you `sample` for reproducibility. b. If you don't want those colums, subset them out first (though with the formula interface it usually doesn't matter if there are extra columns there).

Comment: Is your question about splitting the data into training and test or about dropping columns?

Comment: Both. I am suppose to split the data AND I dont have to include the name and mpg column